# Css trouble with boxes being pushed off page

Tags: css

My picture #minecraftLogo is also my nav is being pushed off the page.  I'm not too sure why that is.  What am I doing wrong here?    I am also getting this weird colour formation around my nav links and Im not too sure why that is.

```
          body{

            border: 0px ;




        }
        section{

            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-bottom: 5px;

            background: #0000FF;
        }

        #Title{
            margin-left: 180px;
            margin-top: 30px;

        }
        #SubtitleOne{
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 500px;
            height: 130px;
            margin-left: 100px;
            margin-top: 120px;
            font-size: 8;


        }

        #SubtitleTwo{
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 500px;
            height: 130px;
            margin-left: 100px;
            margin-top: 10px;


        }
        #SubtitleThree{
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 500px;
            height: 130px;
            margin-left: 100px;
            margin-top: 20px;

        }
        #Links{
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 550px;
            height: 50px;
            margin-left: 25px;
            margin-top: 100px;


        }
        nav{
        position: absolute;

        left: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
        }

        #P1{
        position: relative;
        left: 10px;
        top: -10px;
        }
        #MinecraftLogo{
        position: absolute;



        }
        #YoutubeVideo{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 500px;
        }
        header{
        position relative
        padding: 20px;
        left: 90px;
        margin-top: -10px;
        }

        footer{
        border: 3px dotted;
        border-radius: 25px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px 10px #fd38ab;
        width: 400px;
        height: 50px;
        left: 300px;
        bottom: 500px;
        }
```

Comment: A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help a lot. Without the HTML and a real-world example, it greatly complicates our ability to help you.

Comment: Using absolute positioning should be avoided whenever possible. Use floats + margins + padding to position elements so they flow "naturally" with the page.